# How to read the last XML element of a web file in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am completely new to Visual Basic. I want to create a program that reads only the last element of an external XML file. The only code I have is:

```
Text = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/file.xml")
```

The XML file is as follows:

```
<message>
<sender>John</sender>
<body>Hello!</body>
</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, it looks like you have a string representation of your XML. This is a good start. The next step is to parse the XML. Using [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good tool for this. We can parse it like so:

```
Text = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/file.xml")
Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(Text)
```

I assume when you say last element, you mean the last node inside the root element (which is `message` in this example). You can do that like so:

```
Dim lastElement As XElement = xdoc.Root.Elements.Last()
```

From there you can access the text of the node if that is your goal. You may want to add additional validation, like ensuring the `Elements` collection isn't empty. Right now, this throws an exception is there are no elements inside the root.

Other things to note: You'll need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to `System.Xml` and `System.Xml.Linq` in your project if they aren't there, and ensure the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace is imported.

The XDocument class is a fairly robust way to navigate the contents of an XML file. Use the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to explore what else it can do.